# Magento: Can't save selected value of attribute (Country of Manufacture Attribute used in another attribute)

Tags: php, sql, magento

I created dropdown, and changed source_model column in SQL

`catalog/product_attribute_source_countryofmanufacture`

My new attribute shows country list in backend, but when I select country and save product **value disappears**.

All parameters of dropdown are same like country_of_manufacture attribute.

**What might be a problem for that?** *I’m using 1.7.0.2 ver.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
check whether it returns or not
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'country_of_manufacture';

it's better to create attribute using installer for this you can refer below link

https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/sql/catalog_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0.1-1.6.0.0.2.php#L28
```

Comment: I creadet file test.php in rood, and added attribute then is saves value! thanks!